# What is the ideal widget in PyQt4 in which we can append text but cannot edit it after the text gets populated?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I am working on a personal project in Python that involves creating a user-interface. For that purpose, I have chosen to go with PyQt4.

As part of the GUI code, I need a widget in which we can append text but the requirement is that it should not allow to be edited. A `QtGui.QTextEdit` would solve the purpose of appending text but would not satisfy the second requirement. What widget can I use that satisfies both the requirements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited by who ?

If you don't want that a user can edit it, I think you just need to set the QTextEdit as readonly with QTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)

If you don't want to edit again from the code, I think you just need to check if the control has some text in it: if no, add the text otherwise return an error (or whatever you need)

Comment: Thanks @Gianluca, that was what I was looking for. However, is there any other better widget suitable for this purpose?

Comment: It depend on what type of text you display. QTextEdit can display plain and rich text. If you need only plain text, there is a QPlainTextEdit which is used only for plain text

If you have just a one-line text, you can use a QLineEdit or a QLabel

Answer (score 1):

You could have two TextEdit's, one that is set to readonly that displays the full text and a smaller one below it for entering text to append to the one above.